# How to create an AppSync GraphQL prefixed / complex type `?id=ID` rather than just `ID!`

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Given some knowledge about single table design in DynamoDB, I would like to have generic attribute names.

---

### What I'm trying to create:

```
   PK     |         SK         |    LSI1    | ...
---------------------------------------------------
 PRODUCT  | ?id=1234-1234-1234 | ?type=shoe | ...
---------------------------------------------------
```

Rather than the default:

```
        id       |  type1  | type2 |  ...
------------------------------------------------------
 1234-1234-1234  | PRODUCT | shoe  | ...
------------------------------------------------------
```

---

### My question:

How can I specify the type for SK in the first example? I would like to specify that it's a `String` of format `?id=` and `ID!`

Answer (score 1):

You specify these things in the application code and keep the PK and SK as strings always.

They usually look like this

```
PK                    SK
Type#{productType}    ProductId#{productId}
```

Then productType and productId should also we included as attributes so you can use the data and not extract it from the PK and SK.